# How to surround all space-padded words with braces in AWK?

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a file like this:

```
all <div class="first">these</div> <div class="second">words</div> <div class="second">are</div> <div class="second">marked</div> <div class="second">but</div> these words are not.
<div class="first">this</div> is <div class="second">another</div> <div class="second">example</div> with <div class="second">some</div> unmarked words.
```

I need to place braces around all words that have a space before and after, e.g., the output would be this:

```
all <div class="first">these</div> <div class="second">words</div> <div class="second">are</div> <div class="second">marked</div> <div class="second">but</div> {these} {words} {are} not.
<div class="first">this</div> {is} <div class="second">another</div> <div class="second">example</div> {with} <div class="second">some</div> {unmarked} words.
```

- `all` was not given brace, because there is no space before.
- `not.` and `words.`were not substituted, because there are no spaces after.

I have tried many different things with `awk`, but nothing works quite right. This is the closest I can get:

```
awk '{ gsub(/.[[:blank:]][[:alpha:]][[:blank:]]*/, "{&}"); }1'
```

- Words can only contain these letters: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `g`, `h`, `i`, `j`, `k`, `l`, `m`, `n`, `o`, `p`, `q`, `r`, `s`, `t`, `u`, `v`, `w`, `x`, `y`, `z`, and `ü` and the upper-case equivalents.
- Words cannot contain any other symbols not listed above. For example, if `1`, `á`, and `<` appear somewhere within the two spaces, then it is not considered a match.

Comment: Does it have to be `awk`?  It would be easier with more powerful substitution mechanisms, as in Perl, for example.

Comment: Perl or other software typically found on a Linux installation will be okay too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `awk` script works on the sample data:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
         if ($i ~ /^[[:alpha:]]+$/ && (i != 1 || $0 ~ /^ /))
            $i = "{" $i "}"
       print $0
     }' data
```

For the given input, the output is exactly the desired output.  The condition requires the word in each of the fields to be all alphabetic, and either 'not the first word, or if the line as a whole starts with a blank'.  If there was an all-alpha word at the end, you could add a condition `&& (i != NF || $0 ~ / $/)` in the `if` statement.

I used `[[:alpha:]]` based on the question assuming that in your locale, `ü` is valid as an alpha character.  If you need only plain Latin letters plus `ü` (U+00FC, LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS) and `Ü` (U+00DC, LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS), then you can replace that character class with `[a-zA-ZüÜ]` instead.  Only EBCDIC might get screwed up by the use of `a-zA-Z`, and you'd know if that's a problem for you.  You can revise as necessary to get the characters you're interested in.

Comment: In the case you describe you might alternatively be able to use `[[:alpha:]üÜ]` instead of `[a-zA-ZüÜ]`.

Comment: Yes, you can extend the character class like that.  It all depends on what the `[:alpha:]` part expands to.  In a C locale, that will be basic ASCII 'a-zA-Z', but in other locales, it is likely to include all the accented characters as alphabetic.  It starts to get fraught.  (Quirky aside: for EBCDIC safety, you could use `[a-ij-rs-zA-IJ-RS-Z]`.)

Answer (score 5):

Unless there is another way you can do this, you will need to use *lookahead* and *lookbehind* assertions which are not supported in `awk` or `sed`. With Perl, you could do the following.

```
perl -pe 's/(?<= )([a-zA-ZüÜ]+)(?= )/{\1}/g' file
```

Comment: Does `[a-z]` match `ü`?

Comment: I added the lowercase and uppercase for that character.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `sed` you can create a loop and put braces around the words.

```
$ sed -r ':a;s/ ([[:alpha:]]+) / {\1} /;ta' file
all <div class="first">these</div> <div class="second">words</div> <div class="second">are</div> <div class="second">marked</div> <div class="second">but</div> {these} {words} {are} not.
<div class="first">this</div> {is} <div class="second">another</div> <div class="second">example</div> {with} <div class="second">some</div> {unmarked} words.
```

The character class can be modified to suit your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for `gensub()` and `\s`:

```
awk '{while((new=gensub(/(\s)([[:alpha:]]+)(\s)/,"\\1{\\2}\\3","g")) != $0) $0=new}1' file
```

Comment: +1: This is very clever. My first attempt was using `gensub` but it would fail with three consecutive spaced words with the middle one not being wrapped around with brace. The `gensub` would modify the `$0` to eat up the space for the middle one.

Comment: Yes, you need to use a loop since the matching text only matches once for each invocation of the function. The general caveat is that on the 2nd iteration of the loop you might be operating on text that didn't exist in the original input because it was created as a result of the first operation. Worst case that can take you into an infinite loop so you need to think carefully about what you're doing when using this approach.